# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(UIViewController, sender: AnyObject?) -> Void' and 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Hi Im having an issue with swift 3. there is this bit of code thats giving me an error. I converted it from swift 2.2 to swift 3 and this was the outcome

the few lines of code was swift 2 code and it work fine

the second bit of code is the converted one and its giving me an error

and if I use "=" instead of "==" it gives me this error

```
if show = "followers" {
    loadFollowers()
}

if show = "followings" {
    loadFollowings()
}
```

> Cannot assign to property: self is immutable

its the if statement that is causing the error

```
var user = String()
var show = String()

class followersViewController: UITableViewController {

var usernameArray = [String]()
var picArray = [PFFile]()
var followArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back.png"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(followersVC.back(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn

    let backSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(followersVC.back(_:)))
    backSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(backSwipe)

    if show == "followers" {
        loadFollowers()
    }

    if show == "followings" {
        loadFollowings()
    }
}
```

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '(UIViewController, sender: AnyObject?) -> Void' and 'String'

Comment: Please indent and format your code consistently. As such it is painfully difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3, `UIViewController` has a method named `show` which is shadowing your `show` variable and preventing your view controller from using it.

You can fix the issue by changing the name of your `show` variable to something else and using the `==` comparison.

Comment: can you give us an example?

Answer (score 0):

I added String() and it worked for me

```
if String(show) == "followings"
```